# Font choice not respected in siunitx

Tags: fonts, siunitx

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[default]{lato} %Any other font can be used.
\newcommand\mynum[1]{\num[group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=4]{\the\numexpr(#1)\relax}}
\begin{document}
\Huge  %Just to get the large sized letters

1200 %This produces text in lato font

\mynum{1200} %This is not lato font. I don't know what font is it

\end{document}
```

Now, the `\mynum` command groups the digits correctly but does not respect the font --- lato. This is true whether I compile using latex or xetex.

How do I make `\mynum` command respect the choice of font?

Comment: Wouldn't you want `\sisetup{detect-all, group-separator = {,}, group-minimum-digits = 4}` and then use `\num{1200}`?

Comment: The outcome is exactly as it should be: try `$\mathsf{1{,}200}$` in the same document (which is what `siunitx` is doing, in the end).

Comment: @JosephWright With the small problem that the comma is not `\mathsf`

Comment: Using commas or dots as group separators is explicitly agaist the SI rules. IMHO, it makes no sense to use an SI package to go against fundamental SI principles. Four-digit numbers need not be separated, since it arguably makes reading harder. As for the main problem, it is as Runar has written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be looking for the option `detect-all`, see section 5.1 in the documentation for `siunitx`.

Note that you can always locate the documentation using the command-line/terminal by writing `texdoc siunitx`, and that works for any package. The documentation is also available at http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx

Note that you probably want some consistent settings for your typesetting, including numbers. Therefore, assigning your options for `siunitx` globally would be better than using the settings for only that numbers. Of course, you can use your macro for this, but I really don't see much point in it, as the macro `\num{1200}` would be plenty.

Therefore, using the command `\sisetup{options}` is advisable, as both *Mico* and *egreg* has pointed out.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[default]{lato} %Any other font can be used.
\sisetup{
  detect-all,
  group-separator={,},
  group-minimum-digits=4,
  }
\newcommand\mynum[1]{\num{\the\numexpr(#1)\relax}}
\begin{document}
\Huge  %Just to get the large sized letters

1,200 %This produces text in lato font

\mynum{1200} %Also produces the text in current font

\num{1200}% The same as above, but now extra macro-definition is needed.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\sisetup{detect-all}` would be better, in my opinion.