# Siunitx not changing according to font style

Tags: fonts, siunitx

I am planning on writing my document using opensans font and want to use the siunitx package.
My minimal code is given below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default,oldstyle,scale=0.95]{opensans}
\usepackage[alsoload=synchem,%
            range-phrase=--,%
            repeatunits=false%
            ]{siunitx}  
\sisetup{range-units=single}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\sisetup{detect-family}
\sisetup{detect-weight}
\sisetup{detect-all}
\begin{document}
The temperature measured was \SI{14(1)}{\kelvin} and was observed between time points \SIrange{34}{90}{\second}.

\SI{1.45(20)e-4}{\Molar}

There are 365 days in a year. And I want \SI{2.6(4)e3}{\hectare} land allocation.
\end{document}
```

As instructed in the siunitx manual (page 17 and 19), the `\sisetup{detect-family} and/or \sisetup{detect-weight} and/or \sisetup{detect-all}` should make the numbers and units in the required font. But it does not. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

This is my Output:
[image: My output]

P.S: I have seen this: [Math font changing and siunitx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250152/math-font-changing-and-siunitx), but I am not sure it directly solves my problem.

[Font choice not respected in siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330045/font-choice-not-respected-in-siunitx) posts `\sisetup{detect-all}` as the solution, but as you can see in my code, I have included it and it doesn't seem to work.

EDIT1: I use pdflatex and TexMaker as my frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have noticed that normal math also uses a different font (for example `$14\pm 1$`). This is because the `opensans` package only changes the text font. `siunitx` uses the math font by default.

As a solution you can use the `mathastext` package that uses the current text font for math.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default,oldstyle,scale=0.95]{opensans}
\usepackage[alsoload=synchem,%
            range-phrase=--,%
            repeatunits=false%
            ]{siunitx}  
\sisetup{range-units=single}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\begin{document}
The temperature measured was \SI{14(1)}{\kelvin} and was observed between time points \SIrange{34}{90}{\second}.

\SI{1.45(20)e-4}{\Molar}

There are 365 days in a year. And I want \SI{2.6(4)e3}{\hectare} land allocation.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Explained succinctly, works brilliantly!